# RenderTargetBitmap does not respect ColumnDefinitions width

Tags: c#, wpf, visualbrush, rendertargetbitmap

I need to create snapshot of Grid with some hidden columns (by setting it's ColumnDefinition.Width = 0).

On screen it looks fine, but the `created image` has all columns visible `(does not respect the ColumnDefinitions)`. I red somewhere that it is because the RenderTargetBitmap is looking at different layer where these changes aren't present (Visual layer vs. Layout layer). **Is there any chance to get realistic snapshot of the grid with correct ColumnDefinitions?** I cannot simply use Rectagnel.Fill = VisualBrush, because I need to store these images in cycle (every iteration = new image).

I tried ways like [this snippet](http://blog.avanadeadvisor.com/blogs/markti/archive/2008/04/14/10888.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was needed to force `UpdateLayout()` before each snapshot. I changed the sizes in cycle and layout was updated too late.

Answer (score 1):

Call this method before you create a snapshot of an `UIElement`:

```
public static UIElement GetMeasuredAndArrangedVisual(UIElement visual)
{
    visual.Measure(new Size
    {
        Height = double.PositiveInfinity,
        Width = double.PositiveInfinity
    });

    visual.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, visual.DesiredSize.Width, visual.DesiredSize.Height));

    visual.UpdateLayout();

    return visual;
}
```